# Getting Connection refused while running my code, it might be an issue related to proxy.how to fix it?

Tags: java, twitter, proxy, httpclient

```
//This is my code for returning json response from twitter api which works fine when i am not behind any proxy server 

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class TwitterFeeds {

    static String AccessToken = "xxxx";
    static String AccessSecret = "xxxx";
    static String ConsumerKey = "xxxx";
    static String ConsumerSecret = "xxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(AccessToken, AccessSecret);

        HttpGet request = new     HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxx&count=2"); 

        consumer.sign(request);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();       
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(json_string);
        JSONArray  obj = new JSONArray (json_string);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

// I am behind a proxy server which is blocking my request, the code works fine when i am not behind any proxy server.And getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://api.twitter.com refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at TwitterFeeds.main(TwitterFeeds.java:47)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 8 more
```

This is error which i ma getting showing connection refused. and the code for getting tweets(json format) by user and works when i am not behind any proxy server and does not work when i am behind proxy server

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your `HttpGet` request is missing your proxy settings.

You should do the following:

```
// Here you set your proxy host and port
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(<your_proxy_addess>, <port>); 
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

If you see that's necessary to provide any type of proxy credentials, then the following approach should be taken:

- Create your `HttpGet` request

  ```
  HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(<your_proxy_addess>, <port>);
  RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxx&count=2");
  request.setConfig(config);
  ```
- Provide your credentials to your `HttpClient`:

  ```
  CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
  credsProvider.setCredentials(
          new AuthScope(<your_proxy_addess>, <port>),
          new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));

  HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
          .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  ```

Comment: What is DefaultProxyRoutePlannes and HttpClients, it giving me exception

Comment: `DefaultProxyRoutePlannes` routes requests through the defined proxy.

Comment: which credentials? my system credentials?

Comment: If necessary, yes. It depends whether you need them or not. I'm also behind a proxy and mine requires authentication, so I need to provide my proxy credentials (username and password).

Comment: new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy); is acccepting 2 parameteres ,The constructor DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(HttpHost) is undefined,  org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(HttpHost proxy, SchemePortResolver schemePortResolver)

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent version of this dependency: [httpclient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient).

Comment: getting following errorjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts using the code HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(<your_proxy_addess>, <port>); 
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

Comment: i am using httpclient-4.5.2.jar and also using org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar..tell me which jars to use for above codes

Comment: This are my imports..

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultProxyRoutePlanner;

Comment: You're missing [httpcore](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore) JAR on your classpath. That's where `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts` is defined. Also you should discard [org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1) which as been moved to [httpclient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with the proxy error.

In java, there is at least 2-3 ways to "bypass" the proxy. Each of them have they advantages and inconvenients :

1. Passing arguments to the JVM :

```
$ java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

By doing this, all HTTP connections are affected by this settings. You can have a more slightly dynamic method by following the next point.

2. Using System.setProperty(String, String) :

Like the method above, you can set and unset properties to the JVM but now directly in the code like so.

```
//Set the http proxy to webcache.example.com:8080
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.example.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

// Now, let's 'unset' the proxy.
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", null);
```

This is a great solution if you want to keep everything simple and if your application isn't multi-thread. Like I said before, properties are set for all the JVM.

3. Using the Proxy class :

This solution is more flexible than the two other one.

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("webcache.example.com", 8080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);      
URL url = new URL("http://java.example.org/");
URConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Note: for HTTPS, simply use `Proxy.Type.HTTPS`. For the other methods, use `https.proxyPort` instead of `http.proxyPort` (for example)