# How to use Proxy authentication with Jersey and Apache Http client?

Tags: java, apache, proxy, jersey

I am using jersey client with ApacheConnection Provider.

```
    Builder builder = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    List<Proxy> proxies = ProxyManager.getInstance().select(baseUrl.toURI());
    if (useProxy) {
        ...
        builder.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyUri.getHost(), proxyUri.getPort()));
    }
    RequestConfig requestConfig = builder.build();

    final ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.REQUEST_CONFIG, requestConfig);
    clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

    client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(clientConfig).sslContext(getSSLContext()).build();
    client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
```

But how to add username and password for Proxy authentication?

Seems like apache connection provider does not use the standard java proxy selector mechanisms.

Comment: You could use `DefaultProxyRoutePlanner`: `DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(new HttpHost(<your_proxy_host>, <port>));`. Then you set your client's route planner: `HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();`.

Comment: But where to set username and password?

Comment: For that, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36907908/1346996.

Comment: I see no way to apply this to the jersey scenario. I've only got the requestConfig, and there seems to be no way to manipulate the httpclient

Comment: You're right. The link does not apply to your needs. Take a look at my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution by myself. Unfortunately this is documented nowhere:

```
HttpHost proxyhost = new HttpHost(host,pw);

CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyhost), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pw));
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);

builder.setProxy(proxyhost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add few more lines of code

```
builder.setProxy(proxyhost).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                            .setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());
```

otherwise it wont really authenticate the proxy host I feel. In your case it might be bypassing the proxy. ?